# instance jar file (Snark Client)

Tags: java, oracle, client, bittorrent

On the Snark client website  (http://www.staging.threerings.net/snark.html)  it says to instance a jar file in order to load the client. I referred to this question on the oracle community website (https://community.oracle.com/message/8935199) which lead to saying you can instance the jar file with:

```
Snark.main(args);
```

However when I run my program with that main method call above, it does not display my GUI at all and instead displays this in the console:

```
The Hunting of the Snark Project - Copyright (C) 2003 Mark J. Wielaard

Snark comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and
you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; read the
COPYING file for details.

    snark: Need exactly one <url>, <file> or <dir>.
    Usage: snark [--debug [level]] [--no-commands] [--port <port>]
                 [--share (<ip>|<host>)] (<url>|<file>|<dir>)
      --debug   Shows some extra info and stacktraces
        level   How much debug details to show
                (defaults to 3, with --debug to 4, highest level is 6).
      --no-commands Don't read interactive commands or show usage info.
      --port    The port to listen on for incomming connections
                (if not given defaults to first free port between 6881-6889).
      --share   Start torrent tracker on <ip> address or <host> name.
      <url>     URL pointing to .torrent metainfo file to download/share.
      <file>    Either a local .torrent metainfo file to download
                or (with --share) a file to share.
      <dir>     A directory with files to share (needs --share).
```

I then referred to this website (http://www.klomp.org/snark/) which gave me an example on how to use the client. The examples given did not make any sense to me and looked like command prompts. This is one of the examples on the website:

```
./snark somefile.torrent
```

I have been at this for weeks and any help on how to implement the snark client into my program would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're passing for `args` but it seems like the program is not getting any arguments yet it requires some.  In order to emulate the website example you show, only programmatically from your own program:

```
String[] args =  { "somefile.torrent" };
Snark.main(args);
```

If you have a specific file you're wanting to pass in, you might have to use an absolute file path for the string value.  The important bit is that `main(args)` takes a `String` array that represents command line arguments.  So if you were going to run Snark from the command line with `snark --debug 6` you'd want `args` to be `{"--debug", "6"}`.